# Attributes add to products by MAGMI

Tags: magento-1.8, import, product-attribute, magmi

I just to add many attributes to one "sku" by my csv file. 6500 products and 73000 attributes.
On my csv you can see just 2 sku and attributes. Ofcourse I added before my attributes
"urzadzenie", "rodzaj_urzadzenia","seria","model" in admin.

The problem ist, that magmi just assigned just one attribute from the csv, last one.

`"sku","urzadzenie","rodzaj_urzadzenia","seria","model"
/*first sku*/
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J125"
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J315w"
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J515 W"
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J265w"
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J415w"
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J220"
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J265 W"
"LC985BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J140w"
/* second sku*/
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J6710 DW"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J6910 DW"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J525w"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J725dw"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","DCP","DCP-J925dw"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J625 DW"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J825 DW"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J430 W"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J5910 DW"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J6510 DW"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J5910 DWAP1"
"LC1240BK","Drukarki","Drukarki Atramentowe","MFC","MFC-J6720 DW"`

[image]

Maybe is something like "category_reset", but for attributes???

Answer (score 2):

Finding it hard to understand your question, but it seems you are trying to add multiple values to individual attributes on each SQU.

An attribute can only hold one value.  Therefore the import has executed correctly.

Comment: Yes, you understood me very well.

Comment: I need this attribute just for searchanise. All this attribute are printers. Sometimes, for one sku i have to assigned about 80 printers. How can I do it other way?

Comment: Check [Magmi docs](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_select_%26_multiselect_attributes) regarding Multiselect attributes. At the bottom of the page.